# Is my scatter chart random

Tags: random-generation, pattern-recognition, scatterplot

I used =RAND()*500 in Excel and added to a scatter chart:
[image]

How can I know if it is indeed Random?

Comment: What would it mean for it to be random or not in your context? You know you generated the data from `RAND()`, so what more are you after? Are you trying to assess the quality of the random number generator that is built in to Excel? (There are published papers w/ benchmark tests on that.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It will be as random as the Excel pseudo random number generator is. For pretty much all practical purposes, it is random.  The scatter plot doesn't really help.

Why did you do this?

Comment: thank you for the answer. I need to simulate random raindrops in a field